# Getting JSON from link and then parsing it for Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have JSON data on this link https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/67451/feed/last.json?api_key=VBR3ZDSNGSYJFDDB.
I need to get to get all the data on my app and then Parse it and then use it further. How do i go about it ? Also it'll be appreciated if i could get a little detailed instructions because i'm a newbie.

Comment: this tutorial will be helpful for you for understanding the basic of json parsing  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: My json data is of type {"created_at":"2015-12-02T10:09:48Z","entry_id":373,"field1":"9","field2":"36"} so i need help to read this type of json data

Comment: All you have to do is get a JSONObject from the String you receive from server, and call method getString(key) on it to get the value.

In the tutorial @Aashvi linked you there is information to do it. You should read it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is whole Example from which you can learn.

Basically async task is a background running task, do all things, including data retrieval, network calls etc.

The main point with async task is that you can not change UI components in `doInBackground`, `doInBackground` can only be used for retrieval of data and all the changes in UI components will be done in `OnPostexecute` Method.

```
  private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String jsonData = getPrivateData();
        JsonObject dataObject = JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String createdAt = dataObject.getString("created_at");
        String field1= dataObject.getString("field1");
        String field1= dataObject.getString("field2");
        Int entryId = dataObject.getInt("entry_id");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}

public Sting getPrivateData() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/67451/feed/last.json?api_key=VBR3ZDSNGSYJFDDB");

    try {
       HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
       StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
       int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

       if (statusCode == 200) {
           HttpEntity entity = respons`e.getEntity();
           InputStream content = entity.getContent();
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

           String line;

           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
           }
       } else {
           Log.e(ParseJSON.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

You can further read for this link [androidhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)